# Neovim nvim-tree plugin icons are not showing properly

Tags: fonts, icons, neovim

i have installed configured nvim-tree to show icons. when i use ubuntu regular nerd font it shows the icons fully but when i use other fonts like firacode and Hack it shows half of the icons.

[this is the my nvim screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9VLn.jpg)